# Why the checking condition in the inner loop never true?

Tags: c#, .net

```
for (int i = 0; i < ExtractLinks.FilteredLinks.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < lockedLinks.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (ExtractLinks.FilteredLinks[i].Contains(lockedLinks[x]))
                    {
                        string h = "found";
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to check if the same link exist in both Lists.
FilteredLinks and lockedLinks both type List

I used a break point and in the FilteredLink i saw this link for example:

```
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/112341.shtml
```

And in lockedLinks this link:

```
http://rotter.net/cgi-bin/forum/dcboard.cgi?az=read_count&om=112341&forum=scoops1
```

Both links lead to the same page. So that's mean both are the same.
So in this case it should stop in the break point i added on : string h = "found";
But since it's never stop there i guess something is wrong with my IF condition.

In case it was found i want to remove the link from the FilteredLinks and also from the lockedLinks to remove what suppose to be the same links from both lists. The links are not identical in the address but they are leading to same page so i consider them as the same/identical and they both should be removed.

Comment: I believe your own question answers it...-

Comment: They aren't the same.

Comment: Considering the two links are different why should it resolve to the same in a contains'?

Comment: The links are not identical but since both have inside the number 112341 so they are leading to the same page thats why i consider them as identical and should be removed.

Comment: Then why not write that logic in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the uri format then you can extract the id from the different uri types and compare those:

```
private static string GetArticleIdFiltered(string filtered)
{
    var uri = new Uri(filtered);
    return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uri.LocalPath);
}

private static string GetArticleIdLocked(string locked)
{
    var uri = new Uri(locked);
    var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
    return queryParams["om"];
}

for (int x = 0; x < lockedLinks.Count; x++)
{
    var lockedArticle = GetArticleIdLocked(lockedLinks[x]);
    var filteredId = GetArticleIdFiltered(ExtractLinks.FilteredLinks[i]);
    if (lockedArticle == filteredId)
    {
        string h = "found";
    }
}
```

If you know the id is always numeric you can parse it more accurately and compare ints instead of strings.